# Test if post has a category

Tags: categories

I need to display some HTML only if the post being displayed has a category - not a specific category, just any category at all.

I tried `if (!is_empty(get_the_category($post->ID)))`, but for some reason this isn't working. Has anone else had the same issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `has_category` instead.

`if (has_category('',$post->ID)) ...`

If you want to use it in The Loop, you don't need to specify the ID.

`if (has_category()) ...`

Comment: This is giving me an error for some reason. The code I'm using is: `<?php if (has_category()) { ?>Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php } ?>`. It's weird this is causing an error because I'm using identical syntax for the next line (`<?php if (is_single()) { ?><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number('0 Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></a><?php } ?>`) and that displays fine.

Comment: Are you running WordPress 3.1 or above? has_category was added in WP 3.1.

Comment: No, I'm running WordPress 3.0.4; it's for a large and poorly engineered site that I've inherited from another developer, so I'm reluctant to upgrade for fear of breaking something.

Comment: Welp, there's your problem. Try using `is_object_in_term( $post->ID, 'category')` instead. Or better yet, upgrade. Seriously, running old code sucks rocks.

Comment: Agreed, it's just not an option given the time allotted to the project.

Comment: This would have benefited from a more detailed explanation

Comment: What more detail do you need? The function name is has_category() and it answered the question of the person asking it.